# ListView item animations - Windows store app

Tags: javascript, animation, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I create simple grid application using basic grid example in visual studio and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj244627.aspx#adding_listview_item_animations) tutorial. I expected this animation will work on all item's, but it seems that it works only on first one. My question is, how can I animate this on all item's? And if it is possible to animate randomly(not all at once! Example: windows 8 start menu).

Item template:

```
<div class="itemtemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div class="item">
        <img class="item-image" src="#" data-win-bind="src: backgroundImage; alt: title" />
        <img class="item-image-new" src="#" data-win-bind="src: backgroundImage; alt: title" />
        <div class="item-overlay">
            <h4 class="item-title" data-win-bind="textContent: title"></h4>
            <h6 class="item-subtitle win-type-ellipsis" data-win-bind="textContent: subtitle"></h6>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Js animation:

```
var darkGray = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXY3B0cPoPAANMAcOba1BlAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
var lightGray = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXY7h4+cp/AAhpA3h+ANDKAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
var mediumGray = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXY5g8dcZ/AAY/AsAlWFQ+AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";

// Play the Peek animation
function peekTile(tile1, tile2) {
    // Create peek animation
    var peekAnimation = WinJS.UI.Animation.createPeekAnimation([tile1, tile2]);

    // Reposition tiles to their desired post-animation position
    tile1.style.top = "-250px";
    tile2.style.top = "0px";

    // Execute animation
    peekAnimation.execute();
}

function changeImage() {
    // Get the two image elements
    var images = document.querySelector(".item-image");
    var imagesNew = document.querySelector(".item-image-new");

    // Swap out the old image source and choose the new image source
    images.src = imagesNew.src;
    if (images.src == lightGray)
        imagesNew.src = mediumGray;
    else if (images.src == mediumGray)
        imagesNew.src = darkGray;
    else
        imagesNew.src = lightGray;

    // Reset the elements for the pre-animation position and trigger the animation
    images.style.top = "0px";
    imagesNew.style.top = "250px";
    peekTile(images, imagesNew);
};
```

And interval, that changes images(it is written inside ready function):

```
setInterval(function () { changeImage() }, 4000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `document.querySelector` it will only return the first matching element, which in your case will be the first list item. If you want to animate any random item, just call `document.querySelectorAll(".item")`, pick a random item from the result list and then call `querySelector('.item-image')` on it, proceeding as you currently do.

Comment: I see you are in Windows-team, so I hope, that you could answer me on that question to: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/9da52b5a-b7e6-4f90-9813-76d92e5280cd
Thanks